# How to Signup for Google Inactive Account manager?

Tags: google, account-management

How do I sign up for Google Inactive Account manager? I have gone through support.google.com, read pages related to Google Inactive Account manager but I have not been able to find any link that would really get me started.

I like in India, is it that this facility is still not available in India?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Account Management option at the bottom of your Google account settings page (https://www.google.com/settings/account)